# Subtracting two dates with time in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp

Let's say I have two variables called `AdmittedDate` and `currentDate`. They contain values like

```
"2014-10-13 14:47:44.0"
```

I want to cast them into dates and subtract them and show them in webpage. Can someone help?

Comment: I was able to change the java controller and pass an attribute which has calculated value for date difference. I was wondering if I could get it done by just using front end. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript**

```
var differenceInMin=(new Date(AdmittedDate ).getMilliseconds()-new Date(currentDate).getMilliseconds())/60000;

var diffInHrs=differenceInMin/60;

var diffInDays=parseInt(diffInHrs/24)+" "+parseInt(diffInHrs)+":"+((diffInHrs-parseInt(diffInHrs))*60);
```